# How to take a subset of datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

```
SomeDS.SomeDT subDt = new SomeDS.SomeDT();

subDt = mainds.mainDT.Where(x=>x.status=='Active').CopyToDataTable();
```

Basically the idea is very simple, i have a mainDS which consists of masterset of data and i need only those data that is active and store into another variable under the exact same datatable type. but `CopyToDataTable()` change the type to become `System.Data.DataTable` and it cannot be converted to type `SomeDS.SomeDT`

Comment: what do you mean by subset? do you want only few columns from your "mainds.mainDT" table?

Comment: exact number of columns, only a few rows

Comment: @uɐpuɐɥƆ: Kindly refer to the updated question

Comment: did you got your answer ? See my modified answer. it works perfectly. Tested

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below one

```
SomeDS.SomeDT subDt = mainds.mainDT.Clone();
subDt = mainds.mainDT.Where(x=>x.status=='Active').Select(x=> x).CopyToDataTable();
```

or you can use a foreach too

```
SomeDS.SomeDT subDt = mainds.mainDT.Clone();
foreach (DataRow dr in mainds.mainDT.Rows)
{
   if (/*put some Condition */)
   {
      subDt.ImportRow(dr);
   }
}
```

See below the complete example

```
        DataTable dtMain = new DataTable();
        dtMain.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(string));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("C2", typeof(string));
        dtMain.Columns.Add("C3", typeof(string));
        dtMain.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", "test1", "test1" });
        dtMain.Rows.Add(new object[] { "2", "test2", "test2" });
        dtMain.Rows.Add(new object[] { "3", "test3", "test3" });

        DataTable dtChild = dtMain.Clone();
        dtChild = dtMain.AsEnumerable()
                        .Where(x => x.Field<string>("C2") != "test2")
                        .Select(x=> x).CopyToDataTable();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtChild.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr["C1"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dr["C2"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dr["C3"].ToString());
        }
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: The moment u use `CopyToDataTable()` it will become `System.Data.DataTable` so can't

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep - "CopyToDataTable()" works perfectly but what i missed is ".Select(x=> x)". See my modified answer and an example how it has been implemented